# arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1 1.0.0.CR3 configuring JDBC datasource

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I was trying to use arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1 container to test and EJB3 application. I was trying to figure out how to set up a simple JDBC datasource that could be injected as a resource to a Stateless ejb.

Here is what I have :

```
@Stateless
 public class HelloEJBBean implements HelloEJB {


      @Resource(name="myDataSource")
      private DataSource datasource;




      public String sayHelloEJB(String name) {
                return "Hello " + name;
      }
}
```

also have arquillian.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.com/arquillian"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:glassfish="urn:arq:org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3">
   <glassfish:container>
      <glassfish:bindHttpPort>9090</glassfish:bindHttpPort>
      <glassfish:instanceRoot>src/test/resources</glassfish:instanceRoot>
      <glassfish:autoDelete>false</glassfish:autoDelete>
   </glassfish:container>
</arquillian>
```

and a domain.xml with

```
<domain>
   <applications />
   <resources>
      <jdbc-resource pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedOraclePool" jndi-name="myDataSource"
         object-type="user" enabled="true"/>

     <jdbc-connection-pool name="ArquillianEmbeddedOraclePool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver">
        <property name="user" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="serverName" value="servername"/>
         <property name="DatabaseName" value="dbname"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:1521/dbname"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
   </resources>
</domain>
```

and the simple test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class HelloEJBTest {



    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "helloEJB.jar")
                .addClasses(HelloEJB.class, HelloEJBBean.class);
    }

    @EJB
    private HelloEJB helloEJB;


    @Test
    public void testHelloEJB() {
        String result = helloEJB.sayHelloEJB("Michael");
        assertEquals("Hello Michael", result);

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

... 108 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: myDataSource@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved as: jndi: myDataSource@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties

... 108 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: myDataSource@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved as: jndi: myDataSource@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that your arquillian.xml needs a specific reference (via the glassfish:resourcesXml element?) to your domain.xml. [This arquillian guide](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#setup_persistence_for_glassfish) seems to suggest that, in any case.

Comment: @user1563997, just a suggestion here - do you mind verifying if the issue is resolved through the use of the `configurationXml` property in arquillian.xml as outlined in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/GlassFish+3.1+-+Embedded ? Note that this for the use of a complete GF domain.xml file, which I do not notice in your question.