# Arquillian: Do I need domain.xml and arquillian.xml for minimal Glassfish Embedded tests with Derby DB?

Tags: jpa, junit, glassfish, derby

in the internet I often find recent but contrary information on this topic..., thus I would like to ask a question on minimum requirements.

My goal is to do a very simple integration test of simple EJB 3.1 application:

- Simple JPA 2.0 functionality with EclipseLink
- Arquillian with JUnit for testing
- Maven
- Derby DB (in memory or file in ./target), JTA persistence context.
- Embedded Glassfish in Arquillian

So I just want to do a simple JPA test. I get my Glassfish running in Arquillian, but when doing my JPA stuff, my app always fails to handle the Derby DB (tells me there are no tables etc.), but DDL files look sane.
I played around with providing schema name, user etc. in my persistence.xml, but nothing helps. Sometimes a come accross posts telling me about making changes in a minimal domain.xml for the embedded Glassfish to match my persistence.xml or to adapt the arquillian.xml.

My question is: for this minimal approach - do I really require that src/test/glassfish/domains/domain1/domain.xml or arquillian.xml?

I am quite sure that some time ago I managed to do so with Embedded Glassfish but using Hibernate 4 as JPA provider. I have no access to the project anylonger and thus cannot tell the difference except that I definetely did not add a domain.xml etc.
Posts like ([other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728724/arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3-1-1-0-0-cr3-configuring-jdbc-datasource)) really do confuse me.

Important is that I am not using a managed server, but an embedded one.

Thanks and cheers,
Timo

Here is one of my versions, please see my following comment.

```
<persistence-unit name="localiser-core" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:derby:memory:test;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                  value="database" />

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="target" />
        <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="create.sql"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="drop.sql"/> 
        <property name="eclipselink.debug" value="ALL"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: This is one of the many adaptions of my persistence.xml - I tried many variations with files, different DB names, user und password names etc. It also seems that it can issue SQLs against the DB, but it seems there is just no schema.
Also, ading/removing the JTA datasource name did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

Since your connection URL is: jdbc:derby:memory:test;create=true, what you have told Derby is: connect to a database in the folder 'test', relative to the current working directory of wherever Derby is started, and if that database 'test' is not present in the current working directory, create it from scratch.

So one possibility is that your application has a different current working directory each time, or perhaps that something else in your application is clearing out your current working directory each time you run the application.

Thus Derby doesn't find the previous database in that location, and so it creates a fresh new one.

One way around this is to specify a more explicit location for your database, by using a connection URL such as: jdbc:derby:memory:/users/timo/testdb

Then create the database once, up front, and subsequent to that your application will find the database in the specified location and use it.

Comment: Hello Bryan,thank you very much for your reply!

The thing is that I tried thousand of locations, also w/o "memory" and folders such as "/tmp/" and "target" (using Maven).

However, it seems to create a database, but complains about the missing schema which it dies not create within the database :(
When omitting the schema name, it seems to derive it from the user name, but then still it says that the schema does not exists or at least cannot find the according tables.

Comment: By the way, I though "memory" is a reserved name indicating the DB will completely go into RAM instead of the HDD?

Comment: Oops! I totally overlooked the 'memory' aspect of your URL! That means that your database isn't going to persist beyond a single run of your program. Each instance of your program will create a completely new fresh in-memory copy of the database, which will disappear at the end of the run.

Comment: And yes, if you don't explicitly specify a schema, the default schema name is your user name.

Comment: Hi Bryan,

...and that is the funny point - with the above Derby configuration it seems to create the schema, but without contents - so there are no tables, sequences etc. contained.
The rest is wanted behaviour, namely that the DB disappears after integration test.